# Resetting password with sorcery allows non-matching confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorcery

I am following the [sorcery tutorial](https://github.com/Sorcery/sorcery/wiki/Reset-password) for resetting the password.  I am finding that the code works, even if my password confirmation is different. My user model
has `attr_accessor :password, :password_confirmation`.

The relevant code is from the update action of the `app/controllers/password_resets_controller.rb` i.e.

```
  @user.password_confirmation = params[:user][:password_confirmation]
  if @user.change_password!(params[:user][:password])
    redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Password was successfully updated.')
```

Using pry I can confirm that `@user.password_confirmation` returns 'reallywrong' and `(params[:user][:password]` returns 'foobar', so the confirmation is different from the password, yet `@user.change_password!(params[:user][:password])` returns true.

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not set password confirmation to true in the user model validations.